# Update not happening properly for similar nodes in a TreeViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface, rcp, treeviewer

In a TreeViewer, there are two similar nodes. They use the same data object. When I select the bottom node and modify, it updates the top node but there is no change in the bottom node.

**Before update:**

[image: Before update]

**After update:**

[image: After]

I am using `TreeViewer.refresh(problemNode)` after modifying the name of node. Javadoc of `TreeViewer.refresh(Object element)` says, the tree is updated starting from the given element. Any reason, why it is updating the top node? Since, it uses the same data object, shouldn't both nodes be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the same object in two parts of a tree you can get this behavior.

By 'same object' I mean anything where the `equals` and `hashCode` methods make the objects look the same.

You can work around this by using an `IElementComparer` class for your tree viewer. With this you must implement

```
public boolean equals(Object a, Object b);

public int hashCode(Object element);
```

and make sure that the comparer `equals` method returns `false` when comparing the two elements in the tree and the elements preferably have a different `hashCode`.

Call `TreeViewer.setComparer` to tell the tree viewer about the comparer.